# Multiple windows services under one project creating issues

Tags: service, windows-services

I've created one project for windows services which holds multiple windows services and its installers.

Whenever I install my services project it install both the services but whenever I start my services, it always start 1st service only.

**For Example**

I've created one project "`MyProjet.Services`"

Which holds 2 services

1. `Service1`
2. `Service2`

I installed this services with following commands.

> installutil `MyProject.Services.exe`

its able to create 2 services (`Service1,service2`), able to see them in `Services.msc`

Then I try to start services with commands:

> SC start Service1 param1 param2

Services.msc : **Service1 status: Running**

> SC start Service2 param1 param2

Services.msc : **Service2 status: Running**

But in my log file it shows logs for 1st service only.
In start event of both of the services, I've created log saying "Service1/2 is started".

But whenever I start service2 it always says Service1 is started.
it seems like its not able to start another service.
Is there anything I'm missing?

Regards,
Mox Shah

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/1690989/1544886 helps

Comment: How is your Installer class configured? Also, would you mind showing how are you logging this messages? I did setup a project with the same specs and faced no such problem.